# Как понять имеет ли PE файл доступ к сети

Tags: pe

Как по данным PE файла (.exe, .dll и тд) понять имеет ли он доступ к сети. Где у него хранится эта информация?

Comment: До какой степени достоверности нужно определить подключается ли dll/exe к сети?

Comment: просто сам факт того что он может (да/нет)

Answer (score 2):

Никак, только полным ручным анализом. Получение импортов может быть сделано динамически, да еще и не по именам, а по контрольным суммам. Так что только полным анализом кода.

Comment: То есть нужно просматривать все импорты на предмет того, что файл может запрашивать данные из сети?

Comment: @lenatuseeva импорты не помогут, их вообще может не быть.

Comment: Можна поставить хук на подключение сетевых библиотек.

Comment: Можно пытаться просканировать на подключение сетевых библиотек, и ф-ции LoadLibrary и тому подобные. Но если файл упакованый - его прийдётся разпаковать.

Comment: @nick_n_a не прокатит статический анализ. FS:30, TIB, PEB и уже имеем handle для kernel32.dll без API вызовов. Оттуда по CRC ищем адрес LoadLibrary, грузим либы и тоже по CRC из них дергаем нужные API. Динамика тоже не даст гарантии, видел варианты патчинга DLL в памяти их же кусками с диска, как раз чтобы хуки снять.